# WPF & Caliburn Micro button inside toggle button does not trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

So I have a toggle button with text and inner button. The thing is that I can click anywhere in toggle button are and it triggers, but if I try to click inner button, toggle button triggers again... How can I make that when I click on inner button only inner button action is called?

This is my code:

```
<ToggleButton cal:Message.Attach="TogglePropertyAction" IsChecked="{Binding PropertyEnabled, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Sometext" />
        <TextBlock Text="Another inner text">
            <Button
                Content="InnerButton"
                cal:Message.Attach="InnerBtnAction" />
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

Handle the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events for the `ToggleButton` instead of handling the routed `Clicked` event:

```
<ToggleButton cal:Message.Attach="[Event Checked] = [Action TogglePropertyAction];[Event Unchecked] = [Action TogglePropertyAction]"
              IsChecked="{Binding PropertyEnabled, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Sometext" />
        <TextBlock Text="Another inner text">
            <Button
                Content="InnerButton"
                cal:Message.Attach="InnerBtnAction" />
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```

When you click in the inner button, `InnerBtnAction` is triggered. When you click outside the inner button but inside the `ToggleButton`, `TogglePropertyAction` is triggered.

Comment: This solution does not make any difference. Same thing happens again.. Only toggle button triggers

Comment: When you click in the inner button, InnerBtnAction is triggered. When you click outside the inner button, TogglePropertyAction is triggered. Isn't this what you want? What do you mean by "only" toggle button triggers? When?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what behavior I want... If i click in toggle button scope - toggle button action is called, when I click in inner button scope - toggle button action is still called. Inner button action is never called.

Comment: Are you really sure about that? Set a breakpoint in InnerBtnAction. It certainly works for me.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I have put breakpoints and inner button action is never called

Comment: Then you are doing something strange. Please provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue if you want anyone to be able to help you any further